# javax.validation does not exist

Tags: java, spring

Newbie question... I'm trying to get form validation working with Spring Web using [this tutorial](http://devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring3/mvc/Spring3-login-validation.html), but I'm getting this error:

> package javax.validation does not exist

How can I resolve this? Do I need to install/link additional software? Other `javax` packages such as `javax.servlet` are accessible without a problem. I'm using NetBeans 7.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing a JAR:

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.CR3/

Comment: The folder header says the repository you linked to is deprecated, so I went to this folder instead: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/javax/validation/validation-api/ Also, the current version seems to be 1.0.CR5 at the moment. Anyway... thanks for the advice, it seems to work.